# Type alias for deduced auto return type of member function

Tags: c++, auto

Is there a way, from within a class definition, to deduce the `auto` return type of a member function and use it with a `using` declaration? For example, I want:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() = default;
    auto begin() const { return v_.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return v_.end(); }

  private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
  public:
    using iterator = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().begin());
};
```

This, of course, gives the compiler error

```
error: use of 'auto Foo::begin() const' before deduction of 'auto'
   15 |     using iterator = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().begin());
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

since, presumably, `auto` will not be deduced until after the type `Foo` is complete. However, it would seem that, in principle, the compiler does have enough information at the point of `using iterator = ...` to deduce the type.

One can replace `using iterator = ...` with `template<typename=void> using iterator = ...`, but that means that one has to use the type as `Foo::iterator<>` rather than `Foo::iterator`, which won't work for a Container.

Comment: `using iterator = decltype(v_.begin())` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the same expression that is used to deduce the return type of the method, ie `declval(v_.begin())`:

```
struct Foo {
    std::vector<int> v_;
    auto begin() const { return v_.begin(); }
    using iterator = decltype(v_.begin());
};
```

or a trailing return type:

```
struct Bar {
    std::vector<int> v_;
    auto begin() const -> decltype(v_.begin()) { return v_.begin(); }
    using iterator = decltype(std::declval<Bar>().begin());
};
```

PS: Do not write a constructor that does nothing. If you want to declare it then make it `Foo() = default;`.

Comment: This answer would be clearer if the two suggestions were in separate code blocks. I had to read it a few times to understand you merged both examples here.

Comment: @MooinDuck there you go ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the first solution is incorrect (and is what I tried first) -- it gets the `const`-ness of `iterator` incorrect. The second option works correctly.

Comment: And as for the constructor, that's what happens when I progressively simplify to make a MWE and don't clean it up at the end! Fixed now...

Answer (score 2):

Here we're bitten by rule `If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.`

The deduction of return type for class member won't be complete until class itself can be complete. In addition to what [463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number) wrote, in some cases we may stagger deduction (and separate implementation from interface). Doesn't make sense with simplest classes, but is useful with CRTP.

```
class FooProps {
private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
public:
    auto begin() const { return v_.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return v_.end(); }
};

class Foo : public FooProps { 
    using iterator = decltype(std::declval<FooProps>().begin());
};
```

In its own turn `FooProps` might be a mix-in and then definition of container goes to a trait class.

Answer (score 1):

> However, it would seem that, in principle, the compiler does have enough information at the point of using iterator = ... to deduce the type.

You might think so, but it's possible to supply additional information afterward that changes the answer:

```cpp
// ...
    using iterator = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().begin());

    auto begin() { return v_.begin(); }
    auto end() { return v_.end(); }
};
```

By adding non-`const` overload of `begin` afterward, we change the type of `iterator` from `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` to `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

Instead, write something that does not require `Foo` to be complete, e.g.:

```
    using iterator = decltype(std::as_const(v_).begin());
```

Comment: `std::as_const` is a good thought -- that more straightforwardly expresses what I actually mean.